# installing new package rpy2 issue

Tags: python

unable install rpy2 package

tried with pip install rpy2

```
pip install rpy2

subprocess  calledprocesserror:command  '('c\program files\ R\R3.5.0\R\'cmd' ,'config,'--'idflags')'

error command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py . egg_info check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for rpy2, the developers have said;

> Currently the development is done on UNIX-like operating systems

Although they have  mentioned some [unofficial binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), they also said;

> There is currently close to no support for this platform